# Need the tag [http]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I put this code out for review:

[Stream that opens an HTTP GET and then acts like a normal C++ istream](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38402/http-stream-a-stream-that-opens-an-http-get-and-then-acts-like-a-normal-c-istr)

It is about HTTP socket requests (and I want to discuss HTTP status codes).
But I can't tag it with [http](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/http) (as [https](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/https) is available).

Any chance of adding the [http](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/http) tag?

Comment: It works when I try to add it myself.  Autocomplete shouldn't get in the way there.

Comment: @Jamal: Don't see the http tag on the question yet.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that I've attempted to create it, and it does show up.  Have you already tried that?

Comment: @Jamal: Tried to add it to the question. It still fails.

Comment: Okay, I was able to submit it.  What exactly happened that caused it to fail for you?